# Console input String, output Array<Int> (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to read a single line from the console, convert entered numbers to Integers, and add them to

```
Array<Int>
```

The shortest one-liner I came up with is

```
val na: Array<Int> = readLine()!!.split(' ').map{it.toInt()}.toTypedArray() // Array<Int>
```

This is much longer than e.g python version below. Is it possible to write a shorter code to achieve the same result? This would matter in the compativive programming.

```
na = [int(i) for i in input().split(' ')]
```

Comment: right python version shortest than kotlin, but kotlin's snippet more readable!

Comment: Unless you are competing in codegolf the size shouldn't matter that much

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to declare the variable type, so:

```
val na = readLine()!!.split(' ').map { it.toInt() }.toTypedArray()
```

Does it *have* to be an array? Why can't you use a list? It'll probably be the same thing to you and you won't even notice the difference (if any at all). You'll be able to iterate over it the same way. For a list, you can have:

```
val na = readLine()!!.split(' ').map { it.toInt() }
```

I guess there's no way of making it shorter. `readLine` is longer than `input`,  `toInt` is longer than `int`, and `it` is longer than `i`... there's not much more to do now. And it shouldn't matter, actually ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your Python version doesn't give you an [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), it gives a list. Well, so does

```
val na = readLine()!!.split(' ').map{it.toInt()}
```

which is only longer then Python by a few characters.